# Python: How to get the text label from another program window?

Tags: python, window, textfield, win32gui

I want to read text labels from another program, with Python. I think I have to use WM_GETTEXT, but I don't know how and I couldn't find anything on the internet. My program gets the active window, but doesn't read the text labels. So I hope that somebody can help me.

EDIT: I have added the buffer and SendMessage Part. I can get the text from Editor for example, but not from the program I am trying to get the text labels from.

I have the following code, which I found here on stackoverflow([Get text from popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862454/get-text-from-popup-window)):

```
import win32gui
import time

while True:
    window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
    if 'GLS Exportdatei' in title:
        control = win32gui.FindWindowEx(window, 0, 'static', None)
        buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(20)
        length = win32gui.SendMessage(control, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 20, buffer)

        result = buffer[:length]
        print result
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you click on the window you want to get text from (so it becomes the foreground window) does your app report the correct value?

Comment: No it only displays a blank. The variable result does return an empty string. The title variable gives back the correct window name.

Comment: The title isn't longer than 20 characters, is it?

Comment: The title is longer than 20 characters. The title is: "GLS Exportdatei erstellen... [RG 100000]".

Comment: I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the text of your window has more than 20 characters, then the buffer you have created is too small.  Try expanding it to more than you're likely to need:

```
buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(255)
length = win32gui.SendMessage(control, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 255, buffer)
```

If you want to get to the controls within the main window, then use [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the handle of the parent window.  You may need to do this recursively.

Comment: The title is not the problem. It is the textfields I want to get. Here is an example of what the window looks like: [http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/exampleot.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/exampleot.png/) I try to store these textfields in the result variable.

Comment: @Xirama, whether the text is a title or the contents of the window depends on the window type. It's the same call either way.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help. I now use EnumChildWindows to get the controls.

Answer (score 2):

`win32gui.PyMakeBuffer` has been deprecated. Also, `buffer` is a builtin function, so don't use it as a variable name.

Instead, just do this:

```
buf = " " * 255
length = win32gui.SendMessage(control, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 255, buf)
result = buf[:length]
```